# What is the purpose of the [:] in this line of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

still trying to crack parts of code written by a colleague who took a new job. The following has me stumped.

```
sidd1_fractions = [ ([0.0] * (sidd1_size + 2*flanking_size))[:] for x in range(labels.max()+1) ]
```

Here, he is setting up a series of lists (or arrays) filled with zeros. Not shown is that in later steps he fills these up with data. So this is basically a placeholder for future data.

> My question is that what is the purpose of `[:]`? It normally indicates to slice an entire list but I have seen very similar code which lacks the [:].

Comment: It's a shortcut to make a *copy* of the original list instead of generating another reference to that list.

Comment: The question used as a duplicate is not really a duplicate, it addresses having the `[:]` on the left side of the assignment and not the right.

Comment: thanks Mark. still a bit confused by what you mean by the "original list". What would happen if you left out the [:] vs having it?

Comment: @MarkRansom I think I've found an appropriate duplicate instead.

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't have a real purpose in this particular code. The author of the code seems to intend to copy the `([0.0] * (sidd1_size + 2*flanking_size))` result in order to avoid having multiple lists sharing the same contents. However, that is not a concern here because `[0.0] * (sidd1_size + 2*flanking_size)` is a list containing multiple copies of the float object `0.0`, which **is immutable**.

Comment: thanks Karl. Yes, I ended up running it alone with and without the [:] and the results were identical. you are correct it has not real purpose